# how to call custom data from Django User models

Tags: python, django

im using the built in User model of django and have added few custom fields one of them being the user type, i want to set up conditional statements according to the e_type
this is my code.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from django.contrib import auth
from django.conf import settings

class User(auth.models.User,auth.models.PermissionsMixin,models.Model):
    EMPLOYEE='em'
    MANAGER='mn'
    USER_TYPE=[
        (EMPLOYEE,'employee'),
        (MANAGER,'manager'),
     ]
    e_type=models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=USER_TYPE,default=EMPLOYEE)
    no_of_leaves=models.IntegerField(null=False,validators=[MinValueValidator(1),
                                   MaxValueValidator(24)],default=24)

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from .models import *
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


def home(request):
    user=request.user.e_type
    return render(request,"leaveApp/home.html")
```

Comment: what heppend to `request.user.e_type` ?

Comment: i get this error > 'User' object has no attribute 'e_type'

Comment: What is the value of [**`AUTH_USER_MODEL`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL)?

Comment: haven't set any value..

Comment: That's it. You are trying to *extend the auth model*, but you didn't tell the same thing to Django.  Refe this, [Extending the existing `User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

Comment: thanks for the link .. but in confused if i  should add it under installed apps or anywhere in settings.py